# Handling ListView recycle (duplicate on scroll)

Tags: android, listview

I have ListView with dynamically added images. When the user scrolls down the list, rows duplicates and shows wrong items + losing LayoutParams setting. 
How can I solve this problem?

Here is my getView code:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = view;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ctx.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, true);
        viewHolder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ll_row);
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview_row);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();
    }
    imageResourseId = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(convertStringToArray(imageNames.get(position))));
    for (int i = 0; i < imageResourseId.size(); i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.14f);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(ctx);
        //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(param);
        imageView.setImageResource(ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(imageResourseId.get(i), "drawable", ctx.getPackageName()));
        viewHolder.linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    }
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setTag("images");
    viewHolder.textView.setText(textArray.get(position));
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: how you want show imageResourseId ? is it set of images displayed in one row or what,please describe more

Comment: ArrayList with image names

Comment: Note that you don't need to create a new `ViewHolder` if `rowView != null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is based on how Views are recycled and inflated. The first thing you should do is set the Image's source to null and then set the image you wish. It's a bit early here and I can't recall the specifics.

Comment: Thank you! My bad, I forgot to remove all LinearLayout children's before adding new.